# How to delete multiple documents from Cloud Firestore using Batched writes in angular 5

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular5, angularfire2

as referenced in [firebase cloud firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) Batched writes:

> If you do not need to read any documents in your operation set, you
>   can execute multiple write operations as a single batch that contains
>   any combination of set(), update(), or delete() operations. A batch of
>   writes completes atomically and can write to multiple documents.

how to delete all documents in a collection in using angular 5 ?

```
// Get a new write batch
var batch = db.batch();


// Delete the city 'LA'
var laRef = db.collection("cities").doc("LA");
batch.delete(laRef);



<!--  Delete All Tasks  -->
    <button 
      mat-button mat-icon-button 
      (click)="tasksService.deleteAllTasks(openSnackBar())" 
      matTooltip="Delete All Tasks" 
      class="toolbar-btn" 
      [disabled]="(tasksService.tasks$ | async)?.length == 0">
      <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
    </button>
<!-- Delete All Tasks  -->
```

Comment: you need to loop through the collection and get the doc id then add it to batch. after do batch.commit()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*It's so easy, try this!*

```
private async deleteCollection(path: string) {
    const batch = db.batch();
    const qs = await db.collection(path).ref.get();
    qs.forEach(doc => batch.delete(doc.ref));
    return batch.commit();
}
```

Comment: Beware of exceeding the max batch size of 500 records

Answer (score 4):

I had to add firestore.batch() to the solution
our coturiv friend to make it work.
this is my first contribution.

```
private async deleteCollection(path: string) {
        const batch = db.firestore.batch();
        const qs = await db.collection(path).ref.get();
        qs.forEach(doc => batch.delete(doc.ref));
        return batch.commit();
    }
```